# Where are the secret controllers on the title screen?

Tags: combo-crew

I recently discovered that tapping on certain areas of the title screen awards you with controllers (the currency used to unlock new fighters and moves). How many of these secret controllers are there, and where are they on the title screen?

[image: Combo Crew title screen]